# NSMutableArray property not properly inheriting

Tags: ios, objective-c, inheritance

I have a class, MatchingGame, which contains this property:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *cards;
```

MatchingGame also has a setter to lazily instantiate cards, like so:

```
- (NSMutableArray *)cards
{
    if (!_cards) _cards = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    return _cards;
}
```

The class CardMatchingGame inherits from Matching game so I expected to be able to access the cards property in the sub-class. However, unless I add an `@property` to CardMatchingGame.m's `@interface ... end` code block, I get an `Property 'cards' not found on object of type 'CardMatchingGame'`

I'm new to iOS and Objective-C programming so I don't know if there is quirk about inheritance I am missing. Shouldn't I be able to define cards in the super class and access it in the sub-class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you declared the `@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *cards;` on the .h file of MatchingGame? If so, it will be inherit by CardMatchingGame.

Comment: That did it. I refactored CardMatchingGame into MatchingGame and missed moving the declaration of cards to the header. I only had it in the implementation file. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say ClassB inherits from ClassA. I realize inheritance like this.

**ClassA.h**:

```
@interface ClassA
//...
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *cards;
@end
```

**ClassB.m**:

```
@implementation ClassB

    - (void)foo
    {
        //...
        self.cards = someValue;
        //...
    }
@end
```